# tar --excludes option to exclude only the directory at current working directory, not subdirectories

Tags: tar

I want to tar/zip a directory ./ (current working directory) and exclude files in the directory ./vendor, I happened to also have a subdirectory named vendor at ./public/web/vendor, but I want to keep that. I've tried:

```
tar cfz /private/var/folders/temp/mage6BRQWJ.tar.gz  --exclude=vendor/*     ./
tar cfz /private/var/folders/temp/mage6BRQWJ.tar.gz  --exclude=./vendor/*   ./
tar cfz /private/var/folders/temp/mage6BRQWJ.tar.gz  --exclude="vendor/*"     ./
```

But these both exclude the subdirectory.

I want to use relative path because I want to exclude all .svn (e.g. example) files from all directories, too.

Is there a way, using relative path , to exclude  files in the ./vendor directory but not ./public/web/vendor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is the `--anchored` tag:

GNU tar:

```
tar cfz mage6BRQWJ.tar.gz --anchored --exclude=vendor *
```

bsdtar:

```
bsdtar -czf mage6BRQWJ-1.tar.gz --exclude=^vendor *
```

That works.

Comment: I tried, --anchored is not available in my version of tar. (bsdtar)

Comment: Bummer. I have an older tar 1.26 on Linux and `--anchored` modifies both `--include` and `--exclude` to have **patterns match file name start** compared to the default `--no-anchored` where patterns match after any '/'. Is there a way you can patch your version. I'll check bsdtar, but GNU tar makes is trivial.

Comment: I think that fixed it `--exclude=^vendor`

Comment: Thank you !! could not find anywhere about the ^

Comment: It wasn't in the man page, but looking at the logic GNU tar employed, it seemed to follow that something similar could be done in bsdtar by anchoring the exclude pattern with the normal `^` beginning of string char. Glad it worked. See: "Even a blind squirrel finds a nut every once in a while."